# Is it possible to tell Xcode to not rotate textures in the generated Texture Atlas?

Tags: xcode, ios7, sprite-kit, skspritenode, texture-atlas

I am encountering very poor performance with a long dance animation with 70 frames. Sprite Kit stutters often and the SKSpriteNode has small dimensions.

In the atlas I see many of my frames are rotated 90 degrees. I get the impression Sprite Kit stutters every time it hits one of the rotated frames.

Is there a build setting that will tell Xcode that rotation is not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker). It allows you to disable rotation and besides that has far more features than the built-in TextureAtlas tool.

Xcode's texture atlas tool has no option to disable rotation of images. You can find the tool in `../Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/TextureAtlas`